# Css Attribute Position

Tags: html

when you use the Css attribute position and move things around the page does that mess with the rendering of other websites using it? Ex. say you move a box left on Mozilla FireFox then view it on IE with a zoom of 50% does that box stay in the same position or does it move?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? How do you manipulate the CSS attribute? What do you mean with 'other websites using it'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just change the CSS attributes within your browser (e. g. using the delevoper console), the changes are only local and not transmitted back to the server. So other visitors of that website would not notice any difference.

If you have write access to the CSS stylesheet stored on the server however and you change the attribute declaration therein (and you do not use any vendor-prefixes and the attribute in question is supported by all browsers) then yes, all visitors will notice the change made to that attribute.